# / and // operator functioning the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm having troubles in dealing with these new operators. The output is showing that they are equal, but I do not understand why. In languages like C, these would not create the same result.

Here is my code

```
x = 6
y = 4
t = 3
print " %f e %f" % (x//y, x/y)
```

The output is this:

> 1.000000 e 1.000000

Comment: You would get a syntax error in Python 3.

Comment: If your background is in C, then you should read a tutorial, no?

Comment: This was on the tutorial, and the output was different

Comment: @theBotelho Because presumably your tutorial is in Py3 and you're using Py2.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Or vice-versa. Believe it or not, this is actually not mentioned in the official docs, at least as far as I [could](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html) [find](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators). (I checked 2.7 docs as well.) According to this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm), `//` is supposed to be a divide with floor.

Comment: This brought up an interesting quirk in the Python language, which isn't covered by the docs. It's a good question, if deceptively simple to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot more to the story here than the [type of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621340/712526). In Python 2.7, you might expect that `/` truncates, and that `//` floors, which would sometimes lead to different answers even though the output is coerced to an int in both cases. This is simply not the case.

In [Python 2](https://repl.it/languages/python), where the output of both operators is integral, the results of both is the same, regardless of the sign of the input.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
 > (6/4, 6//4)
=> (1, 1)
 > (-6/4, -6//4)
=> (-2, -2)
 > (6/-4, 6//-4)   # Shouldn't really be different than the above
=> (-2, -2)        # ... and, isn't.
```

Using [Python 3](https://repl.it/languages/python3), you can see that they do indeed perform different operations. Specifically, `/` does not round at all.

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
 > (6/4, 6//4)
=> (1.5, 1)
 > (-6/4, -6//4)
=> (-1.5, -2)
 > (6/-4, 6//-4)
=> (-1.5, -2)
```

These operators don't seem to be well documented for either Python 2 or Python 3, as I mentioned in my earlier comment on the question, so any behavior could be considered "correct."

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, division between two integers results in an integer, just as it does in C. It doesn't matter if you're using `/` or `//`.

In Python 3, division between two integers with `/` results in a floating point number, but with `//` results in an integer.

Based on the `print` statement in your code, you're using Python 2.